# linkedhashmap for parse Json Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, hashmap

is there an analogue of java`s linkedHashMap
in swift5?

I have a json of similar structure,

```
"details": {
            "Общее": {
                "Тип транспортного средства": "Легковой автомобиль",
                "Производитель": "TESLA",
                "Модель": "Model X",
                "Год выпуска": "2017",
                "Город Производитель": "Fremont",
                "Штат Производитель": "California",
                "Страна Производитель": "United States (USA)"
            },
            "Двигатель": {
                "Тип топлива - первичный": "Электрический"
            },
            "Экстерьер": {
                "Кузов": "Спортивный внедорожник (SUV) / Многоцелевой автомобиль (MPV)",
                "Двери": "5",
                "Общий вес транспортного средства": "Класс 2E: (2722 - 3175 кг)",
                "Количество колес": "4",
                "Колесная база (дюймы)": "116.7"
            },
            "Интерьер": {
                "Расположение руля": "Левый руль",
                "Количество рядов сидений": "2",
                "Количество сидячих мест": "5"
            },
            "Механическое": {
                "Оси": "2"
            },
            "Система пассивной безопасности": {
                "Тип ремней безопасности": "Ручной",
                "Передние подушки безопасности": "1-й ряд (водитель и пассажир)",
                "Подушки безопасности подколенные": "1-й ряд (водитель и пассажир)",
                "Расположение боковой подушки безопасности": "1-й ряд (водитель и пассажир)"
            },
            "Система активной безопасности": {
                "Адаптивный круиз-контроль": "Необязательный",
                "Антиблокировочная тормозная система (ABS)": "Стандарт",
                "Немедленное торможение (CIB)": "Стандарт",
                "Обнаружение слепых зон (BSD)": "Стандарт",
                "Электронный контроль стабильности (ESC)": "Стандарт",
                "Антипробуксовочная система": "Стандарт",
                "Предупреждение о прямом столкновении (FCW)": "Стандарт",
                "Предупреждение о выходе из полосы движения (LDW)": "Стандарт",
                "Система поддержки движения по полосам(LKS)": "Необязательный",
                "Система задней видимости (RVS)": "Стандарт",
                "Помощь при парковке": "Необязательный",
                "Система контроля давления в шинах (TMPS)": "Прямой"
            }
        }
```

headers and strings can change, and I can not control the data model that the external server gives in my request

in the android version there is a short and simple entry for such a structure,

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> details;
```

but in ios?

Comment: What about [String: [String: String]]? Why does it have to be linked, is order important?

Comment: I am need to parse this object in Model

`struct Details: Hashable, Codable`            
 Now for each line I need to write var string: string

Comment: probably not....
I need to output data in a similar format 
 [https://ua.carplates.app/number/AA9999TC] ---> scroll to `Расшифровка VIN` and press the button

Comment: simple answer: No, there is not something like LinkedHashMap in swift